# How to get copy and paste-able tables accross browsers for export to word-processors?

Tags: html, css, html-table, copy-paste, word-processor

When I copy and paste a table styled with CSS from a browser to a word processor I get very different results: Firefox neglects CSS styles, Chrome copies only the content of the table, and Safari works only with Pages. Is there a way to copy paste cross browser, ideally with CSS?

```css
    #css {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    #css td {
      border: 1px solid;
    }
```

```html
<table id="css">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Test1</td>
          <td>Test2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZrVXdG

Comment: I don't think we can control this behavior. It is up to the browsers to implement these features

Comment: @Prajwal: Thanks. I'd hoped that there is a way around it somehow. But I guess one cannot even tamper with copy and paste using javascript only.